# SharePoint user migration error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

I'm facing an issue while moving a user.

I'm first retrieving the user object:

```
$Site = Get-SPSite "https://mysite.mydomain.com"
$Web = $Site.OpenWeb()
$User = $Web.EnsureUser("domain\userid")
```

And then I'm executing the below to migrate the user:

```
Move-SPUser -Identity $User -newalias "domain\userid" -IgnoreSID
```

But when I do so, I get an error:

> Move-SPUser : The given key was not present in the dictionary. At
>   line:21 char:1
>   + Move-SPUser -Identity $User -newalias "domain\userid" -IgnoreSID
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PCmdletMoveUser:     SPCmdletMoveUser)
>   [Move-SPUser], KeyNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMoveUser

Comment: Are you moving the user from one domain to another?

Comment: User domain has not changed. But the authentication type has changed (NTLM to claim-based)

Comment: Have you converted the web application to Claims? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx

Answer (score 6):

When switching from one AD-environment to another, you sometimes end up with users who don't get imported correct. You see them when they don't have first name and last name when they are logged in to SharePoint. They have \ visible instead.

But let's start from the beginning and migrate the users with the following command:

```
STSADM –o migrateuser –oldlogin OLDDOMAIN\user1 –newlogin NEWDOMAIN\user1 –ignoresidhistory
```

After that you need to run a full user profile synchronization. When this is done, continue and see which users where not imported correct.

```
# Clean up accounts that is not imported correctly

$upsa = Get-SPServiceApplication | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -like "User Profile Service Application"}

# List all user accounts that is not imported correctly
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upsa -GetNonImportedObjects $true

# Remove user accounts not imported correctly 
# Uncomment line below to run
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upsa -PurgeNonImportedObjects $true

# Run a full User Profile Service Syncronisation, and make sure users
# end up in Profile database.
# If not, users who log in will create new NonImportedObject accounts
```

This might have to be repeated several times, especially if you're in a live environment where users login during the day. Eventually these orphan user profiles will disappear.
If you have a lot of users, the script will take a lot of time - so please be patient unless you get an error from PowerShell.
Good Luck!